# Windows Phone Emulator with PC Keyboard on Apple Mac

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

This one has me stumped - so if anyone has an answer that would be fabulous

I have a Macbook Air with a US Keyboard.
I am running Windows 8.1 in Bootcamp, and Im developing a Windows Phone 8 app with Visual Studio 2013.

Everything is great except I cant get the computer keyboard to work with the emulator, so Im having to tap out all of my input - which is painful.

According to the Emulator Help you need to activate the PC keyboard by hitting either PAUSE/BREAK or Page-Up.

Of course, my laptop doesnt have these keys, and the standard mappings (Fn-ArrowUp & Fn-Shift-F12) dont work - and in fact Ive tried just about every possible combination of keys I can think of and nothing works.

Does anyone know how I can get this done ! (why Microsoft doesnt include a menu with these things on is beyond me).

Thanks anyone

Comment: You could try making a very short program that uses [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to simulate a Pause/Break hit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one is pretty mysterious for some reason. Different people are getting this to work in different ways.

For what it's worth, for me pressing `fn-page down` enables the keyboard in the emulator.

I am using a Surface Pro, Windows 8, and a full size, wired, Macintosh keyboard.

I also know some people have had success with `fn-esc`, which just closes the onscreen keyboard for me.